# How do I bind my kubernetes cluster master to an elastic ip with AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

I ran the install script:

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

And it set up my cluster just fine. The problem is that the master was not on an elastic ip. So I went to the VPC settings in the AWS management console and bound it to one. This obviously changed the ip of the master which I correspondingly changed in `.kube/config`.

Now whenever I try to do anything with kubectl (e.g. `kubectl get pods`) I get the error: `error: couldn't read version from server: Get https://NEW_IP/api: x509: certificate is valid for OLD_IP, 10.0.0.1, not NEW_IP`.

Is there a correct way to bind the master to an elastic IP? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing: `kube-down` then `export MASTER_RESERVED_IP=[NEW_IP]` and then `kube-up`